# IBOutletCollection with Xamarin possible?

Tags: ios, xamarin, storyboard

So, I'm looking into converting an already existing iOS app into Xamarin, I've pulled in the `*.storyboard` file and all was going well until I came to implement a `ViewController` with an `IBOutletCollection`.

There is no way to edit these collections within Xamarin Studios `*.storyboard` editor, and it doesn't seem to be pulling these collections into an array for me to use in the `*.desiger.cs` file.

Am I doing something wrong or is this feature not supported by Xamarin?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Xamarin supports collection.
Open the designer file and you should see a your collection as an array something like this

```
[Outlet]
    UIKit.UIButton[] weekDaysButtonCollection { get; set; }
```

Storyboard files are best to be edited in Xcode
 https://i.stack.imgur.com/uad8t.png

Comment: I'm not getting anything for my collections :(. If they're definitely supported I'll take a look at what I'm doing wrong. Cheers.

Comment: Add right, so pulling an existing storyboard with IBOutletCollections doesn't seem to register them, but once you add them manually again it works fine. Thanks!